# Speed up execution of caching an image in Android

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap

I have the following code to save an image to the cache directory of my application. The method is called within a separate `Runnable()` which I hoped would speed up the application. As it stands the compressing of the Bitmap is very expensive on the processor and causes the rest of the application to be very slow. How can I speed it up?

```
public void combineImages(Bitmap bmp, int count, int count2){                   
        Bitmap bottomImage = bmp.copy(Config.RGB_565, true);
        float width = bmp.getWidth();
        float height = bmp.getHeight(); 
        bmp.recycle();  

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image1);
        Bitmap topImage = myBitmap.copy(Config.ARGB_4444, true);
        myBitmap.recycle();
        myBitmap = null;

        Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(bottomImage);
        // Then draw the second on top of that
        comboImage.drawBitmap(topImage, (width / 2) - 200, (height / 2) - 160, null);

        topImage.recycle(); 
        topImage = null;

        // bottomImage is now a composite of the two.

        // To write the file out to the Cache:
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir() + "/" + path);
            bottomImage.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 50, os); //Here it is most expensive and what slows the app down

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: which thread are you posting the `Runnable` to?

Comment: @techiServices: It is posted to another Runnable instance which in turn is run on the main UI Thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a separate thread to run the method, either by creating a new inner class that extends `Thread` and call the method or by creating a new `Thread` and passing the `Runnable` as a constructor argument.  If it is an ongoing task, i.e. you have many bitmaps to process, you may want to have a look at `HandlerThread` or `IntentService`.

Comment: I have this already, I have the UI Thread which I create a Thread object which calls a method saveImage() in it's Runnable() method, within this method there is another Thread object and in the Runnable() method the code above is called. I don't think it is a threading problem at all, the app is very fast when not using the compress method on the Bitmap object.

Comment: @SamRowley:  sorry i misunderstood, from your comment it appeared that you were running that method on the UI thread.  Are you testing on a physical device or the emulator?  Looking at the android source the compress method calls a native function.

Comment: I am running it on 2 different devices (HTC Desire and Samsung Nexus S), it has sped up by changing the compress format to JPEG rather than PNG on the Nexus but it's still really slow on the Desire.

Comment: @techiServices - Yes I have, I used setDaemon(true); for the threads I want right in the background. I'm guessing it is a hardware issue being slow on the HTC, it works very well on the Nexus S.

Comment: @SamRowley:  i would suspect the same since the compress method runs a native c function, however the priority i am talking about is set via the `Thread.setPriority` method or on the constructor, for example, using `Thread.MIN_PRIORITY`.